# VueJs select default values from database

Tags: javascript, vue.js, element-ui

I am using [el-select](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/select#select) but i'm unable to select default values in edit page.

It selects same amount of data but wrong details. Let show you by this image:

[image: one]

> So this data of mine has 2 value but the values are `core 17` and `core 19` but here as you see i get `core 1` and `core 1` so i get the right amount but wrong data.

## Code

`template`

```
<el-row :gutter="10">
    <el-col :span="24">
        <el-form-item  label="Cores">
            <el-select style="width: 100%;" filterable multiple clearable v-model="form.cores" placeholder="Select Cores">
                <el-option
                    v-for="core in cores"
                    :key="core.id"
                    :label="core.name"
                    :selected="core.id === form.cores.id"
                    :value="core.id">
                </el-option>
            </el-select>
        </el-form-item>
    </el-col>
</el-row>
```

`script`

> I commented every part to you don't get confused

```
data() {
    return {
        cores: [], // core 1 till core 20
        form: {
            name: '',
            position: '',
            link_id: '',
            cable_id: '',
            cores: [], // core 17 and core 19
            description: '',
            longitude: '',
            latitude: '',
            _method: 'PUT',
        },
    }
},
methods: {
    fetchRegion() {
        axios
            .get('/api/admin/closures/'+this.$route.params.id, {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('access_token')
                }
            })
            .then(response => {
                // removed the rest to make it clean.
                this.form.cores = response.data.data.cores; // this return my default (stored data) core 17, core 19
                this.cores = response.data.cores; // this return all cores from 1 to 20 including 17 and 19 in order if user wants to add more etc.
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log('error', error);
            });
    },
}
```

**Any idea how to select right values?**

## Update

Console result of `this.form.cores`

[image]

Comment: Is `this.form.cores` inside `.then()` a array? What value does it have inside `then`?

Comment: @palaѕн yes is array i will update my question for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method first to get only the selected ids from the `form.cores` array like:

```
form.cores.map(x=>x.id)   // returns [17, 19]
```

Then use [`.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method to set the default values here like:

```
:selected="form.cores.map(x=>x.id).includes(core.id)"
```

Comment: it says: `Property or method "id" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property`

Comment: Sorry, a typo occurred. try again.

Comment: you mean like this? `this.form.cores = response.data.data.cores.map(x=>x.id);`